# From email to Django

Tags: django, email

There is someway to insert content from email to Django Admin?

For example, I will receive emails from notifications coming from notifications@facebook, and then, I will catch this email, do some formatting and insert (automatic) on a mySQL database.

Somebody know how can I do something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: how do you receive the email ? do you have a process polling the server ?

Comment: have you considered using a provider with http/rest callbacks, e.g. mailgun.com? I don't have any affiliation with them, just one example how  this can be done easily. btw, here's a possible duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128041/process-received-email-with-python-or-django

Comment: Check out [Lamson Project](http://lamsonproject.org/). It would allow you to programmatically handle incoming emails using python.

Comment: If the email is saved on the computer; you should be able to retrieve it and read it like any other file. You might want to make a program to see if a file is created in the folder and have that call your function for handling the file.

Comment: have you looked at celery to regularly check you inbox for notifications?  You can then write some code to format put it in your database.

Comment: can you narrow down your question a bit ?