# Parse all email body html with Python

Tags: python, email

Basically, I want to parse all emails body from my gmail using Python. There are few solutions on StackOverflow e.g. the closest I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225586/checking-email-with-python) where he use `poplib` from Python to parse all emails. Another one is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874360/python-how-to-parse-the-body-from-a-raw-email-given-that-raw-email-does-not) where he use `.get_payload()` to get email body

However, when I use parse email using `poplib` (as from above example) then each email message I do `message.get_payload()` to get email body, the string I get is not the same as html from email itself i.e. it has string like `3D`, `= \n`, `amp;` etc. in my parsed email body.

I wonder if it's a problem with `POP` protocol so I need to use other protocol such as `imaplib` (but I don't know how to parse all email like `poplib`). Or, I can modify given [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225586/checking-email-with-python) to get correct email body.

Answer (score 6):

`message.get_payload(decode=True)` will be your best friend for this :)

According [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload):

> Optional decode is a flag indicating whether the payload should be decoded or not, according to the Content-Transfer-Encoding header.

HTH