# Controlling LED lights to blink when a new email arrives

Tags: python, email, arduino, led

I'm kind of a newbie, but I'm trying to connect my emails to an LED strip perhaps or a light bulb for my final year project, how would I go about doing this by using an Arduino board?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I would split this project in three major parts:

1. **Email monitoring**

   First, you need to know when a new email message arrives in your inbox. For this task you might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225586/checking-email-with-python) useful.
2. **Serial communication between Python and Arduino**

   Once you know how to identify new email messages, you can send a message to your Arduino board by using serial communication. This message could be a simple string `BLINK`. You can use the [pySerial library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python) for sending messages to the Arduino board. In order to read the message in Arduino, take a look at [this official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read). Whenever you receive a string `BLINK` you can trigger a code to blink the lights.
3. **Controlling LED lights**

   If you are a newcomer I recommend you start small. First, try finishing this project by [blinking a single LED](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink). As long as you have mastered that, you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips) to control a LED stripe.

   Good luck!