# Read through an email and parse it into strings with python

Tags: python, email

I am wondering if it is possible to read through an email and parse the subject of the email into a string. I have a device that sends an email to specific inbox every time there is an error with the device. I want a script to read through the email as soon as it arrives in the inbox and get the device ID from the subject line and store it into a string. I was thinking I could use python because there are email modules for it, and it is what I'm most comfortable with. Would this be possible in Python? Or any other language for that matter? I have looked online, but I could not find anything that pertains to what I want it to do. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225586/checking-email-with-python

Comment: just a note for posterity: the answer listed in Ahsanul's link doesn't include a python 3.x compatible solution.  IMO until one is added it should be considered too deprecated when flagging future duplicates.